# Get the Location without internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-maps

I try to get android current location without using internet and I create the  code in below but does not display any value in `TextView`

```
package com.example.ahmed.gbs_location;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
TextView latitude;
TextView longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb1);
    longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb2);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ahmed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    else
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude.setText(String.valueOf(d));
    longitude.setText(String.valueOf( location.getLongitude()));
    latitude.setText(String.valueOf(( location.getLatitude())));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

}
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.ahmed.gbs_location">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I did not know why there are  value  for  latitude and   longitude  display  in `TextView`?

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or real device?

Comment: *but does not display any value in textview* ... this is exactly what this code does as by definition you don't have permissions ...

Answer (score 1):

If your `targetSdkVersion` is `>22`, try requesting runtime permission & request location update from `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

For runtime permission click [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)!

Also your code will only work if location services is enable in device setting.
Since you are neither checking location services status nor requesting to enable it.

Try using `FusedLocationProviderApi` you don't have to use intent, check [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates)!